# How to Sum After Fetching A specific Colum Data in a Date-Range in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-8

Please am working on Inventory system, I want to get the inventory Records or Transactions from a date range and sum certain part of the result. the opening stock should show the stock as at the **$from** Date and sum the other results in between. The closing stock should also show the closing stock as at the **$to** Date. The summation shouldn't affect the **opening stock and closing stock**

This is what I did please in my Controller, I need assistance;

```
    $request->date = 02/14/2022 - 02/20/2022;

    $value = explode(' - ', $request->date);
    $source1 = $value[0];
    $date1 = new DateTime($source1);
    $from = $date1->format('Y-m-d');

    $source2 = $value[1];
    $date2 = new DateTime($source2);
    $to = $date2->format('Y-m-d');

    return $report_ledger = \DB::table('item_stock_ledgers')
        ->selectRaw('item_name as item_name,item_unit as item_unit,item_opening_stock as item_opening_stock WHERE(date = $from),sum(item_wastage) as item_wastage,
                    sum(item_manual_closing_stock) as item_manual_closing_stock, sum(item_purchases) as item_purchases, sum(item_recieved) as item_recieved,
                    sum(item_issue) as item_issue, sum(item_sales) as item_sales, sum(item_adjustment) as item_adjustment, 
                    sum(item_manufacturing) as item_manufacturing,sum(item_cons_manufacturing) as item_cons_manufacturing, 
                    item_closing_stock as WHERE(date = $to), sum(item_variance) as item_variance')
        ->groupBy('item_name')
        ->groupBy('item_unit')
        ->whereBetween('date', [$from, $to])
        ->where('station', auth()->user()->station)
        ->get();
```

Comment: This part here `$request->date = 02/14/2022 - 02/20/2022` seems invalid. I suppose it needs a semicolon on end and you are not declaring it as a string, which you infer it should be by your `explode()` on the very next line.

Comment: I just want to say..that’s the results from $request->date